# Strange plot in PSpice Student after reducing maximum step size

Tags: pspice

I have run 10m simulation in PSpice Student 9.1 with Analysis Type: Time Domain (Transient) with max step size 100u and I get such plot:

[image: max step size 100u]

I wanted my plot to be more smooth so I have changed max step size to 100n and to my surprise plot looks like that:

[image: max step size 100n]

Can anyone explain me what has happened and how can I smooth my plot ?

**EDIT: CIRCUIT**
[image]

Rc = 5k, Re = 2k, Ro = 10k, Rg = 40k, V1 = 20V, V2 = 6V, VOFF -1V, VAMPL = 1mV, FREQ = 1000

Comment: Where's the circuit you're simulating?

Comment: Here is my circuit one stage OE amplifier.

Comment: What does "SCHEMATIC-dz_czasu" look like?

Comment: What would you like me to provide ? I can insert some file but I do not know with what .extension or I can insert printscreen of any Simulation Setting tab but I also do not which one would you like to see ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have solved the issue. The problem was with Relative accuracy of V's and I's option. It is under Options tab in Simulation Settings.